# What is the model for checking if a GSI key exists or not in DDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a pretty straight forward question

I want to know if some GSI hash key exists or not.

The best I can find right now is

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> queryExpression;             
// Logic for constructing query
queryExpression.withIndexName(SomeIndexName);
QueryResultPage<T> queryResponse mapper.queryPage(T.class, queryExpression, someMapperConfig));
```

Here query result page contains a list of results, I can check if that list has anything and conclude whether it exists or not.

The obvious problem is the efficiency drop when there are things that are present. Is there a way to not move the contents of the item across network IO for the purpose of verification (i.e. a server side total validation of the predicate of checking if some GSI key exists or not)?

Answer (score 0):

When writing an item with, for example, Put-Item you can [add a condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites) specifying the key must not exist. This way DynamoDB checks whether the provided key is already taken and will give an error when you try to put something in. Just catch the error and then you know the key was already taken.